# How to add custom nested attribute to a Kong Open Telemetry message

Tags: kong, open-telemetry, apm, elastic-apm

I need to send a runtime environment type (prod, dev, test, etc.) from the Kong (3.2.2-alpine) OTEL Plugin to my ELK APM traces.

I'm using OTELCollector 0.75.0 for that purpose. I tried to specify service.environment in kong.yml (via resource_attributes) and otel.yml (processors.attributes.actions), but in both ways I'm receiving this field in Labels section of message, named in snake case: labels: {service_environment: dev}. How can I add custom attribute in exact place I want?